# How to get git details into already configured eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, git

I've got a project I've checked out with git, and I have imported it to Eclipse.
Later I have added git plugin to Eclipse, but Eclipse doesn't recognize my details. I don't know if it doesn't see my .git folder or doesn't want to see it, when I click on Team submenues, I get the standard Share project menu.

How can I get Eclipse to see my past transactions and details from git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, to answer myself and possible other stumblers here, I've clicked on **Share project**, then I've added it as a new git project and when it came to asking me about which repository to use, it already offered the one I need :)

So I guess it was already there under my nose :)